# div alignment isn't the same in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

Geetings

I am coding a website UI using Tailwindcss and am facing a problem in how to align the left side and right side. When I changed mt-4 is not working!!

here is my code:

```
<section id="aboutus">
        <div class="h-screen bg-[url('../Imges/1BG.png')]"></div>
        <div class="-mt-[320px] ml-[460px]"><img class="h-40 w-40" src="Imges/logoicon.svg"></div>

        <div class="container flex flex-col px-4 mx-52 space-y-12 
        md:space-y-0 md:flex-row">
            <!-- left side -->
            <div class="flex flex-col my-20 space-y-8 md:w-1/2">
                <!-- about part -->
                <div
                    class="flex flex-col px-4 py-2 max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 md:py-1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="px-36"><img class="h-12 w-12" src="Imges/icon1.png"></span>
                    <h2 class="pt-4 max-w-sm text-4xl font-bold text-center text-LBlue">About us</h2>
                    <p class="flex flex-row max-w-sm text-center text-DarkGrey"><br>Nuances is an IT company
                        thatprovides solutions to enhanceyour business flow. We help
                        you build your business website or mobile app in a smart way.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <!-- Values part -->
                <div
                    class="flex flex-col mt-72 px-4 py-2 max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 md:py-1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="px-36"><img class="h-12 w-12" src="Imges/icon3.png"></span>
                    <h2 class="pt-4 max-w-sm text-4xl font-bold text-center text-LBlue">Values</h2>
                    <p class="flex flex-row max-w-sm text-center text-DarkGrey"><br>Taking care of the interests of our
                        customers and
                        providing the best level of performance and safety.</p>
                    <br>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- right side -->
            <div class="flex flex-col mr-60 space-y-8 md:w-1/2">
                <!-- misson part -->
                <div
                    class="flex flex-col px-4 py-2 max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 md:py-1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="px-36"><img class="h-18 w-24" src="Imges/icon2.png"></span>
                    <h2 class="pt-4 max-w-sm text-4xl font-bold text-center text-LBlue">Mission</h2>
                    <p class="flex flex-row max-w-sm text-center text-DarkGrey"><br>is add value and productivity for
                        our clientele through innovative system integration of converence digital technologies
                        and through providing</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <!-- vision part -->
                <div
                    class="flex flex-col px-4 py-2 max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-md shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 md:py-1">
                    <br>
                    <span class="px-36"><img class="max-h-14 w-14" src="Imges/icon4-.png"></span>
                    <h2 class="pt-4 max-w-sm text-4xl font-bold text-center text-LBlue">Vision</h2>
                    <p class="flex flex-row max-w-sm text-center text-DarkGrey"><br>We are focused on bringing first
                        world information
                        technology to the Saudi market. We shall accomplish this by partnering with leading technology
                    </p>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and here is the result : in the attachement.

so how to fix this probelm?

Comment: You haven't seemed to have included an attachment. Could you also give more details about what you are trying to achieve? I see no `mt-4` in the supplied code.